# How to filter a Generic ListView?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am using a CBV `ListView`, 
The problem is, the view returns a list of ALL notes on the system.
What I would really prefer is for the list to only return the 'notes' that are associated with a particular `CandProfile` (model)

The notes model is :

```
class CandidateNote(models.Model):

  candidate   = models.ForeignKey(CandProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='candidatenotes_cand')
  note_by     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='candidatenotes_user')
  job_note    = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
  date_added  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I am new to Django and querying, and don't really know how to approach this in a Class based view....my initial thoughts were :
Maybe I should modify the `get_queryset` method.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your intuition is correct - modifying the `get_queryset` method is the right place to filter the results.

Answer (score 4):

In views.py,

```
class UserNote(generic.ListView):
     template_name = **add your template name here **
     context_object_name = 'user_notes'

     def get_queryset(self):
          return CandidateNote.objects.filter(user__username=self.kwargs['username'])
```

You can show it on html, 
{% for notes in user_notes %}
** your template **
{% endfor %}